# How retrieve all of records in Azure storage tables using PowerShell or Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am using Azure CLI and I can connect to storage table and get Items from the table using bellow code in a loop for each table in my storage:

```
"get metrics from $table"
$temp_result = (az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection-string $connection_string --accept "none" --filter "CounterName eq '\Memory\PercentUsedMemory' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesReceived' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted' or CounterName eq '\Processor\PercentProcessorTime'" --select "TIMESTAMP" "Average" "CounterName" | ConvertFrom-Json)
($temp_result.items).Length
```

And the result is something like this:

```
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20171007
88
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20171017
688
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20171027
464
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20180326
88
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20180405
72
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20171007
1000
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20171017
1000
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20171027
1000
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20180326
1000
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20180405
1000
```

But in one of my tables I have more than 37000 records and I want to get all of them. I tried to set `--num-results 9999` like bellow:

```
"get metrics from $table"
$temp_result = (az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection-string $connection_string --accept "none" --filter "CounterName eq '\Memory\PercentUsedMemory' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesReceived' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted' or CounterName eq '\Processor\PercentProcessorTime'" --select "TIMESTAMP" "Average" "CounterName" --num-results 9999 | ConvertFrom-Json)
($temp_result.items).Length
```

but it will return this error:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"One of the request inputs is not valid.\nRequestId:d8ccda32-f002-0034-2619-cd42aa000000\nTime:2018-04-05T20:07:56.7891454Z"}}}
```

Can you guide me what is wrong and how I can get all of records in Azure storage tables using Powershell or Azure CLI?

## UPDATE:

As Zhaoxing Lu said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680850/how-retrieve-all-of-records-in-azure-storage-tables-using-powershell-or-azure-cl?answertab=active#tab-top) answer, I tried to use --marker. but there is some problems.

first of all, it's my current code:

```
$connection_string = (az storage account show-connection-string --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $storageAccount | ConvertFrom-Json).connectionString
$table_list = (az storage table list --connection-string $connection_string | ConvertFrom-Json).name

if ($table_list.Length -eq 0)
{
    "There is no table in '$storageAccount' storage"
}
else
{
    "There is "+$table_list.Length+" tables stored in $storageAccount."
    ###########################################
    ## Find those tables that stored metrics ##
    ###########################################
    $tables = @()
    Foreach($temp_table_name in $table_list)
    {
        if ($temp_table_name.StartsWith("WADMetrics"))
        {
            $tables += $temp_table_name
        }
    }

    if ($tables.Length -eq 0)
    {
        "There is no table starting with 'WADMetrics' as prefix in storage ($storageAccount) tables, then we can't detect any Metric."
    }
    else
    {
        ($tables.Length).tostring()+" tables stored metrics"
        Foreach($table in $tables)
        {
            "get metrics from $table"
            $is_more_results = 0
            $nextMarker = @{}
            $nextpartitionkey = ""
            $nextrowkey = ""

            Do
            {
                $filter_str = "CounterName eq '\Memory\PercentUsedMemory' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesReceived' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted' or CounterName eq '\Processor\PercentProcessorTime'"
                $temp_result

                if ($nextpartitionkey -ne "")
                {
                    "Call with marker"
                    $temp_result = az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection-string $connection_string --accept "minimal" --filter "CounterName eq '\Memory\PercentUsedMemory' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesReceived' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted' or CounterName eq '\Processor\PercentProcessorTime'" --select "TIMESTAMP" "Average" "CounterName" --num-results 50 --marker $nextMarker
                }
                else
                {
                    "Call without marker"
                    $temp_result = az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection-string $connection_string --accept "minimal" --filter "CounterName eq '\Memory\PercentUsedMemory' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesReceived' or CounterName eq '\NetworkInterface\BytesTransmitted' or CounterName eq '\Processor\PercentProcessorTime'" --select "TIMESTAMP" "Average" "CounterName" --num-results 50
                }

                $temp_result = [string]$temp_result
                $temp_result = $temp_result | ConvertFrom-Json
                ($temp_result.items).Length

                if (($temp_result.nextMarker.nextpartitionkey).Length -gt 0)
                {
                    #there is more items in the requested query
                    $nextpartitionkey = $temp_result.nextMarker.nextpartitionkey
                    $nextrowkey = $temp_result.nextMarker.nextrowkey
                    $nextMarker["nextpartitionkey"] = $nextpartitionkey
                    $nextMarker["nextrowkey"] = $nextrowkey
                    $is_more_results = 1
                }
                else
                {
                    $is_more_results = 0
                }
            } While ($is_more_results -ne 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Above code will return bellow output:

```
There is 16 tables stored in testresource********.
10 tables stored metrics
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20171007
Call without marker
50

items                                                                                                                                                        
-----                                                                                                                                                        
{@{Average=10.095833333333333; CounterName=\Memory\PercentUsedMemory; TIMESTAMP=2017-10-16T22:00:00+00:00; etag=W/"datetime'2017-10-16T23%3A00%3A05.500086...
Call with marker
az : ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
At line:66 char:36
+ ... mp_result = az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: 'str' ob...attribute 'get':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\knack\cli.py", line 197, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 319, in execute
    result = cmd(params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(AzCliCommand, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\knack\commands.py", line 109, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 420, in default_command_handler
    result = op(**command_args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\multiapi\cosmosdb\v2017_04_17\table\tableservice.py", line 730, in 
query_entities
    resp = self._query_entities(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\multiapi\cosmosdb\v2017_04_17\table\tableservice.py", line 776, in 
_query_entities
    next_partition_key = None if marker is None else marker.get('nextpartitionkey')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:75 char:47
+                 $temp_result = $temp_result | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

0
```

I tried to pass --marker directly using bellow code:

```
if (($temp_result.nextMarker.nextpartitionkey).Length -gt 0)
{
    #there is more items in the requested query
    $nextpartitionkey = $temp_result.nextMarker.nextpartitionkey

    $nextMarker = $temp_result.nextMarker
    $is_more_results = 1
}
```

but the error was same:

```
There is 16 tables stored in testresource********.
10 tables stored metrics
get metrics from WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20171007
Call without marker
50

items                                                                                                                                                        
-----                                                                                                                                                        
{@{Average=10.095833333333333; CounterName=\Memory\PercentUsedMemory; TIMESTAMP=2017-10-16T22:00:00+00:00; etag=W/"datetime'2017-10-16T23%3A00%3A05.500086...
Call with marker
az : ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
At line:66 char:36
+ ... mp_result = az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: 'str' ob...attribute 'get':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\knack\cli.py", line 197, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 319, in execute
    result = cmd(params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(AzCliCommand, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\knack\commands.py", line 109, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 420, in default_command_handler
    result = op(**command_args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\multiapi\cosmosdb\v2017_04_17\table\tableservice.py", line 730, in 
query_entities
    resp = self._query_entities(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\multiapi\cosmosdb\v2017_04_17\table\tableservice.py", line 776, in 
_query_entities
    next_partition_key = None if marker is None else marker.get('nextpartitionkey')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:75 char:47
+                 $temp_result = $temp_result | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

0
```

I even tried to remove --marker and pass `nextpartitionkey` and `nextrowkey` by query!, it didn't return any error, but it will return always same and the loop will continue forever.

```
if ($nextpartitionkey -ne "")
{
    $filter_str = $filter_str + " and PartitionKey eq '$nextpartitionkey' and RowKey eq '$nextrowkey'"
}
$temp_result = az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection-string $connection_string --accept "minimal" --filter $filter_str --select "TIMESTAMP" "Average" "CounterName" --num-results 50
```

## UPDATE 2:

I tried passing marker as stirng. bellow string is a sample of marker that I used as string:

```
"nextMarker": {
    "nextpartitionkey":  "1!260!OjAwMkZzdWJzY3JpcHRpb25zOjAwMkYzMTM1Nzc1YTowMDJEMTA2ZDowMDJENGVmODowMDJEODlhYTowMDJEN2VkYjM2YjRjMzU2OjAwMkZyZXNvdXJjZUdyb3Vwcz
owMDJGVGVzdFJlc291cmNlR3JvdXAyOjAwMkZwcm92aWRlcnM6MDAyRk1pY3Jvc29mdDowMDJFQ29tcHV0ZTowMDJGdmlydHVhbE1hY2hpbmVzOjAwMkZjcHV1c2FnZXRlc3Q-",
    "nextrowkey":  "1!72!OjAwNUNNZW1vcnk6MDA1Q1BlcmNlbnRVc2VkTWVtb3J5X18yNTE4OTQxMzExOTk5OTk5OTk5"
}
```

I also tried this one as string:

```
{
    "nextpartitionkey":  "1!260!OjAwMkZzdWJzY3JpcHRpb25zOjAwMkYzMTM1Nzc1YTowMDJEMTA2ZDowMDJENGVmODowMDJEODlhYTowMDJEN2VkYjM2YjRjMzU2OjAwMkZyZXNvdXJjZUdyb3Vwcz
owMDJGVGVzdFJlc291cmNlR3JvdXAyOjAwMkZwcm92aWRlcnM6MDAyRk1pY3Jvc29mdDowMDJFQ29tcHV0ZTowMDJGdmlydHVhbE1hY2hpbmVzOjAwMkZjcHV1c2FnZXRlc3Q-",
    "nextrowkey":  "1!72!OjAwNUNNZW1vcnk6MDA1Q1BlcmNlbnRVc2VkTWVtb3J5X18yNTE4OTQxMzExOTk5OTk5OTk5"
}
```

in both I got this error:

```
az : ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
At C:\Users\Reza\Desktop\ndbench\Azure\Automation\01_get_metrics\add_target_to_tables - runbook.ps1:87 char:36
+ ... mp_result = az storage entity query --table-name $table --connection- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: 'str' ob...attribute 'get':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\knack\cli.py", line 197, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 319, in execute
    result = cmd(params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(AzCliCommand, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\knack\commands.py", line 109, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 420, in default_command_handler
    result = op(**command_args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\multiapi\cosmosdb\v2017_04_17\table\tableservice.py", line 730, in 
query_entities
    resp = self._query_entities(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\multiapi\cosmosdb\v2017_04_17\table\tableservice.py", line 776, in 
_query_entities
    next_partition_key = None if marker is None else marker.get('nextpartitionkey')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\Reza\Desktop\ndbench\Azure\Automation\01_get_metrics\add_target_to_tables - runbook.ps1:112 char:47
+                 $temp_result = $temp_result | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

then in summery, the problem is how I should pass `--marker`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the CLI. A fix will be out in our next release, v2.0.32.
Basically the properties being given to the `--marker` parameter weren't being parsed out.

Read here for more info: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6194

Answer (score 1):

You got the error because it's not possible to return 9999 results at a time. As the [Query Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks) doc indicates, the maximal value for `-num-results` is 1000.

In order to get all the entities in a table, you'd need a loop of [az storage entity query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/entity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-entity-query) via continuation object. To get the next page of query result, please set `--marker` to the value of `$temp_result.next_marker` from previous iteration.

Comment: I have edited the question. can you please read the update part?
seems you are right but there is more problems

Comment: Could you try to convert $nextMarker back to string before passing it to Azure CLI？

Comment: I did it, and I wrote the results in "UPDATE 2" section.

Comment: @Zhaixing Lu can you please check the Update 2 section?